# Mocking Database.QueryLocator in Unit Tests using fflib Apex Mocks

Tags: apex, unit-test, querylocator, fflib, apexmock

Assume we have some basic `AccountSelector` class that has different implementations of the selector method. QueryLocator variation is helpful once we need to take advantage of [SOQL for loops](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm) or to use it in the `start()` method of batches.

```java
public with sharing class AccountSelector extends fflib_SObjectSelector {

    public override SObjectType getSObjectType() {
        return Account.SObjectType;
    }

    public override List<SObjectField> getSObjectFieldList() {
        return new List<SObjectField>{ 
            Account.Id,
            Account.Name
        };
    }

    public List<Account> byIds(Set<Id> ids) {
        return (List<Account>) Database.query(soqlByIds(ids));
    }

    public Database.QueryLocator locatorByIds(Set<Id> ids) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(soqlByIds(ids));
    }

    private String soqlByIds(Set<Id> ids) {
        fflib_QueryFactory queryFactory = newQueryFactory()
                .setEnforceFLS(true)
                .setCondition('Id IN :ids');
        return queryFactory.toSOQL();
    }
}
```

Some service class uses `AccountSelector` and I need to unit test that service class using fflib Apex Mocks:

```java
@IsTest(IsParallel=true)
private class SomeServiceUnitTest {

    @IsTest
    static void shouldReturnAccount() {
        // Create Mocks
        fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();
        AccountSelector accSelectorMock = (AccountSelector) mocks.mock(AccountSelector.class);
        // Given
        List<Account> accountsMock = new List<Account>();
        Id accId = fflib_IDGenerator.generate(Account.SObjectType);
        accountsMock.add(
                new Account(
                        Id = accId,
                        Name = 'TestName'
                )
        );
        mocks.startStubbing();
            mocks.when(accSelectorMock.sObjectType())
                .thenReturn(Account.SObjectType);
            mocks.when(accSelectorMock.byIds(new Set<Id>{ accId }))
                .thenReturn(accountsMock); // Works as expected
            mocks.when(accSelectorMock.locatorByIds(new Set<Id>{ accId }))
                .thenReturn(???); // Need to get/create an instance of Database.QueryLocator to mock
        mocks.stopStubbing();
        Application.SELECTOR.setMock(accSelectorMock);
    }

}
```

So the problem here is that when we want to mock `accSelectorMock.locatorByIds()` method invocation, we need to get an instance of `Database.QueryLocator`. The known way to get it is `Database.getQueryLocator()` static method which can take either `String query` or `List<SObject> query` param e.g:

```java
Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id FROM Account'); 
Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Account]);
```

`Database.QueryLocator` instance represents a server-side database cursor but in case if we want to write pure unit tests without any DML operations(e.g. inserting test accounts) it seems impossible to get a mock of `Database.QueryLocator` instance somehow.
So the questions are:

> Can we get an instance of `Database.QueryLocator` that points to some test records without first inserting them?

> How to mock a selector method that returns `Database.QueryLocator` in the unit tests in terms of `fflib Apex Mocks`?

Comment: would it help if you changed the signature of the selector method to return an iterable instead (as Database.QueryLocator also implements `Iterable`... List<Sobject> implements iterable so you could mock a list of sobjects; if application need is for batchable, I've done what @willard answered

Comment: Since Apex Mocks uses Stub API under the hood neither `Iterator` nor `Iterable` cannot be mocked as return types or parameter types due to the limitations https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_stub_api.htm

Comment: doc says Iterator cant be a return type but does not restrict Iterable; I have certainly created mock selectors that return Database.QueryLocator (which implements Iterable)

Comment: @cropredy Can you please share an example as an aswer?

Answer (score 5):

Currently, I came up with some ugly but efficient solution for mocking `Database.QueryLocator` and to be precise, its substitution.

1. To change the return type of `AccountSelector.locatorByIds()` method from `Database.QueryLocator` to `Object`:

```java
public with sharing class AccountSelector extends fflib_SObjectSelector {
    public override SObjectType getSObjectType() {
        return Account.SObjectType;
    }

    public override List<SObjectField> getSObjectFieldList() {
        return new List<SObjectField>{ 
            Account.Id,
            Account.Name
        };
    }

    public List<Account> byIds(Set<Id> ids) {
        return (List<Account>) Database.query(soqlByIds(ids)));
    }

    public Object locatorByIds(Set<Id> ids) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(soqlByIds(ids));
    }

    private String soqlByIds(Set<Id> ids) {
        fflib_QueryFactory queryFactory = newQueryFactory()
                .setEnforceFLS(true)
                .setCondition('Id IN :ids');
        return queryFactory.toSOQL();
    }
    
}
```

I also tried

```java
    public Iterable<Account> locatorByIds(Set<Id> ids) {
        return (Iterable<Account>) Database.getQueryLocator(soqlByIds(ids));
    }
```

and

```java
    public Iterator<Account> locatorByIds(Set<Id> ids) {
        return (Iterator<Account>) Database.getQueryLocator(soqlByIds(ids)).iterator();
    }
```

method variations and they work as expected but they have one significant drawback in terms of fflib Apex Mocks - they cannot be mocked due to [Stub API Limitations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_stub_api.htm).
Every time invoking the `mock()` method on the `fflib_ApexMocks` instance with `Selector` type parameter of the `Selector` class which has at least 1 method that returns `Iterator<T>` or `Iterable<T>` fails with:

```java
fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();
AccountSelector accSelectorMock = (AccountSelector) mocks.mock(AccountSelector.class);
```

> System.TypeException: No type arguments provided for a parameterized type: **System.Iterable** (or **System.Iterator**)
> Class.System.Test.createStub: line 93, column 1
> Class.fflib_ApexMocks.mock: line 67, column 1

However, there are no limitations to mock the method that returns `Object`.

2. So now the `locatorByIds()` method can be mocked next way:

```java
@IsTest(IsParallel=true)
private class SomeServiceUnitTest {

    @IsTest
    static void shouldDoSomething() {
        // Create Mocks
        fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();
        AccountSelector accSelectorMock = (AccountSelector) mocks.mock(AccountSelector.class);
        // Given
        List<Account> accountsMock = new List<Account>();
        Id accId = fflib_IDGenerator.generate(Account.SObjectType);
        accountsMock.add(
                new Account(
                        Id = accId,
                        Name = 'TestName'
                )
        );
        mocks.startStubbing();
            mocks.when(accSelectorMock.sObjectType())
                .thenReturn(Account.SObjectType);
            mocks.when(accSelectorMock.locatorByIds(new Set<Id>{ accId }))
                .thenReturn(accountsMock); 
        mocks.stopStubbing();
        Application.SELECTOR.setMock(accSelectorMock);
    }

}
```

3. To add some dynamic casting directly in the `Service` (or in another suitable layer):

```java
public with sharing class SomeService {

    public void someMethod(Set<Id> accIds) {
        AccountSelector accSelector =
            (AccountSelector) Application.SELECTOR.newInstance(Account.SObjectType);

        Object accLocatorLike = accSelector.locatorByIds(accIds);
        Iterator<Account> accIterator;
        if (accLocatorLike instanceof Database.QueryLocator) {
            accIterator = (Iterator<Account>) ((Database.QueryLocator) accLocatorLike).iterator();
        } else if (accLocatorLike instanceof List<Account>) {
            accIterator = (Iterator<Account>) ((Iterable<Account>) accLocatorLike).iterator();
        }
        while (accIterator != null && accIterator.hasNext()) {
            Account acc = accIterator.next();
            // Processing the record returned by iterator
        }
        /* OR
        Iterator<SObject> sObjIterator;
        if (accLocatorLike instanceof Database.QueryLocator) {
            sObjIterator = ((Database.QueryLocator) accLocatorLike).iterator();
        } else if (accLocatorLike instanceof List<Account>) {
            sObjIterator = ((Iterable<SObject>) accLocatorLike).iterator();
        }
        while (sObjIterator != null && sObjIterator.hasNext()) {
            Account acc = (Account) sObjIterator.next();
            // Processing the record returned by iterator
        }
        */
    }
}
```

The main point here is that we should perform dynamic casting for the entity returned by the `locatorByIds()` method depending on the context. When the returned entity is of type `Database.QueryLocator` it can be cast to `Database.QueryLocator` apriori. When the returned entity is of type `List<Account>` it can be cast to `Iterable<Account>` because `List<T>` implements `Iterable<T>`. So now we have either `Database.QueryLocator` or `Iterable<Account>` instance and both have the `iterator()` method since `Database.QueryLocator` implements `Iterable`. Since `Database.QueryLocatorIterator` implements `Iterator` both iterators can explicitly be cast to `Iterator<Account>`.

Although this solution looks a bit ugly, the performance cost of casting is cheap enough in JAVA and AFAIK Apex uses JVM.

**PS** Hopefully, someone will find a more sophisticated solution. Please write in the comments so that I can improve the answer.

**PSS** Please vote for [Add Generics to the Apex Language](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000aDnYAAU) everyone who has not yet voted.

Comment: this is pretty clever

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can mock it.  I assume you need this b/c you want to mock out some records to test `Batchable` classes?  If so, I just call each method (`start`, `execute`, `finish`) independently.  The records I want to process are passed in manually within the execute method.  The first method here will require you to have real records inserted for your tests.  The 2nd method you can mock out the records you want to process:

```
public inherited sharing class SynchronousBatchRunner {
    public static void run(Database.Batchable<SObject> batchableClass) {
        Database.QueryLocator locator = (Database.QueryLocator) batchableClass.start(null);
        Database.QueryLocatorIterator it = locator.iterator();
        List<SObject> records = new List<SObject>();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            records.add(it.next());
        }
        batchableClass.execute(null, records);
        batchableClass.finish(null);
    }

    public static void run(Database.Batchable<SObject> batchableClass, List<SObject> recordList) {
        batchableClass.start(null);
        batchableClass.execute(null, recordList);
        batchableClass.finish(null);

    }
}
```